# UICollectionViewCell wrong size

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, layout, storyboard

I have a problem with `UICollectionViewCell`.

My `UICollectionViewCell`'s width = `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width` and it works fine before I add `UILabel` into the cell with constraints for left and right edges. If I add only for left it's ok. but when for both I have an issue.

Bug state :

[image: Bug] 
[image]

Normal state:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 50) 

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return .zero
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
}
```

You can try this code.
In storyboard -> UICollectionView -> Change Estimate size as None in Size Inspector

Comment: The problem was in Estimate size. Thank you!

Comment: Actually I also was calling estimated size which was the source of a problem where as soon as I added constraints that connected both sides of my sub constainer added to a cell it caused the container to collapse to the size of the content.

Answer (score 1):

you can set right constrain with greater than equal to constrain, so it can adjust appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Dont add a right constrain to the uicollection cell. 
Simply provide a top and left (leading) constraint and the drag the uilabel to your desired width and then set a width constraint. 
That should be all you need to get your desired outcome.